# verify email address on Linux

Tags: linux, email

I am using command like `sendmail -bv example@othesite.com` to verify some email address to confirm the address is  valid or not before sending actual email to people.
it works for most sites I tested. But sometimes, I am using the sendmail
for some website that will give me all pass no matter what the address name I put for
the same site.

For example:

`sendmail -bv yyyyyy@othersite.com`

where `yyyyyy` can be anything that also passes the command and always reported out  "`yyyyyy@othersite.com`  verified". It seems correct but I think that should be something wrong behind.  Why ?

Other command checking mail address on linux will be reliable and available, how and what command does this?

Comment: Hi you can use  nslookup  – type=mx gmail.com to verify the domain for identifying the mail id you can use telnet check this link http://www.labnol.org/software/verify-email-address/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command and link have solved the issue.

-nslookup command  help to find out  mail server address for examplesite.com

nslookup -type=mx examplesite.com;

-https://superuser.com/questions/224015/how-to-check-if-email-address-does-exist

The answer instruction in the link help to verfiy the email address completely

Answer (score 16):

**Short answer**:
There is no 100% reliable way to verify the existence of a recipient email address other than actually send a message there and have the recipient click a link in the message body.

**Explanation**:
What most of these address verifcation tools do is contact the recipient server, start a SMTP session and use the SMTP "RCPT TO" (or sometimes "VRFY") command check if the server responds with *200 OK* or *550 User Unknown*. This works if the server does recipient verification, but many servers simply accept everything first and then bounce the message later if the recipient doesn't exist. Even with recipient filtering enabled some systems (for example Exchange 2013) only respond with "User unknown" after the SMTP DATA stage which means you actually have to send a full message before you get the result.

More advanced verification systems also check for bounces, but even this is not reliable. Getting no bounce could mean the recipient address exists but it could also mean the address probe was quarantined or you simply didn't wait long enough for the bounce.

Comment: The shortest explanation of the inconsistent behavior of host responses I've seen so far. Nicely done.

Answer (score 3):

**In short:** 
No, there's no command that does this.

**Gaining confidence in existence:**
While there is no completely accurate way to verify the existence of an email address without an end-user clicking a signed link from an email, there are long, detailed [guides](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0452.html) on how one might approach getting a kind of "confidence level" of an address's existence. A rough breakdown of these levels are:

1. The host exists and has mail exchanges (DNS lookup with nslookup or equivalent).
2. A MX accepts an envelope to the address, but is a forwarding server (could be a false positive).
3. A MX accepts an envelope to the address, and is a "core" server (often not accessible externally).
4. A real message was sent that didn't bounce, given enough time (assuming the server isn't just keeping mum).
5. A real message was sent and the recipient indicated so.

And mapping the levels to what they mean:

- (0) Definitely does not exist.
- (1,2) Is indeterminable.
- (>=3) Exists.

You could figure out which MX's accept envelopes to obviously nonexistent addresses, and thereby be able to distinguish between confidence levels 2 and 3.